# The relationship between code behind class and aspx generated class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I was reading a book says that "a Web Form’s code-behind class was the base class for the class generated by the runtime from the .aspx file itself, as the picture below shows:
[image: HelloWorld Example]

I don't know how the generated class looks like, as I only deal with aspx.cs which is the code-behind class.

So let say I have a .aspx file that have some controls like textboxes, do the generated class generated by .aspx file contains Textbox class?  and how this generated class inherit the code-behind class, I'm really confused, can anybody post an example code of generated class generated by .aspx file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated classes are stored here:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root
```

Replace the version in the above path with the version of your framework. There will be many files in there but you can delete them all to start afresh. Then restart the web application in question and you will see a brand new folder (with a numeric name) will be created in the *root* folder. Inside the folder you will see many files but if you sort them by type, one of the *CS File*s will be the one generated for the .aspx page. The name will not be a friendly name so you will have to keep opening them and search for `nameofpage_aspx`. For example, if the aspx page is named `About`, search for `about_aspx`. If you do not find it, search for it in another file and one of them will be for `about_aspx`.

You may also look for the first line in the file which starts with `#pragma checksum` and it will have the name of the .aspx page. Not all files will have this line.

In those *CS File* types are the generated code which will be used by asp.net and you can examine its contents in more details if you want. Please do not ask me to explain the details of what is in those files but I am sure if you search online, you will find info on that.